# Webscraping doesn't fill up the file with all information asked from all pages

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm beginnerin python and I need to scrape restaurants name, socioeconomical status, name clients, review date, titre review and review from 10 to 40 pages of only one restaurant(python3.7 and beautiful soup). But when I open the csv file, I have all information about only first reviewer. This is my code :

```css
csv_file = open("lebouclard.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ";")
csv_writer.writerow(["inf_rest_name", "rest_eclf", "name_client", "date_rev_cl", "titre_rev_cl", "opinion_cl"])
for i in range(10,40):
    url = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d947475-Reviews-or10-Le_Bouclard-Paris_Ile_de_France.html".format(i)).text
    page_soup = soup(url, "html.parser")
    gen_rest = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"page"})
    for rest in gen_rest:
        rname= rest.find("h1",{"class":"ui_header h1"})
        inf_rest_name = rname.text
        print("inf_rest_name: " + inf_rest_name)
        econ_class_food = rest.find("div", {"class":"header_links"})
        rest_eclf = econ_class_food.text.strip()
        print("rest_eclf: " + rest_eclf)
    for clients in gen_rest:
        client_info = clients.find_all("div", {"class":"info_text"})
        name_client = client_info[0].text
        print("name_client: " + name_client)
        date_review = clients.find_all("span", {"class":"ratingDate"})
        date_rev_cl = date_review[0].text.strip()
        print("date_rev_cl: " + date_rev_cl)
        titre_review = clients.find_all("span", {"class":"noQuotes"})
        titre_rev_cl = titre_review[0].text.strip()
        print("titre_rev_cl: " + titre_rev_cl)
        opinion = clients.find_all("p", {"class":"partial_entry"})
        opinion_cl = opinion[0].text.replace("\n","")
        print("opinion_cl: " + opinion_cl)
        csv_writer.writerow([inf_rest_name, rest_eclf, name_client, date_rev_cl, titre_rev_cl, opinion_cl])
csv_file.close()
```

I tried to eliminate the for client in gen_rest and put:

```
client_info = rest.find_all("div", {"class":"info_text"})
name_client = client_info[0].text
print("name_client: " + name_client)
date_review = rest.find_all("span", {"class":"ratingDate"})
date_rev_cl = date_review[0].text.strip()
print("date_rev_cl: " + date_rev_cl)
titre_review = rest.find_all("span", {"class":"noQuotes"})
titre_rev_cl = titre_review[0].text.strip()
print("titre_rev_cl: " + titre_rev_cl)
opinion = rest.find_all("p", {"class":"partial_entry"})
opinion_cl = opinion[0].text.replace("\n","")
print("opinion_cl: " + opinion_cl)
```

but it shows me the same information in the scv file. After I decided to eliminate the find_all and the [0] but The results were the same. What am I missing?... I have read the others questions about this but I don't find my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following where f string is used so a value for next set of reviews is passed into the string during loop

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open("lebouclard.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(["inf_rest_name", "rest_eclf", "name_client", "date_rev_cl", "titre_rev_cl", "opinion_cl"])

    with requests.Session() as s:
        for offset in range(0,40,10):
            url = f'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d947475-Reviews-or{offset}-Le_Bouclard-Paris_Ile_de_France.html'
            r = s.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            if not offset:
                inf_rest_name = soup.select_one('.heading').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                rest_eclf = soup.select_one('.header_links a').text.strip()

            for review in soup.select('.reviewSelector'):
                name_client = review.select_one('.info_text > div:first-child').text.strip()
                date_rev_cl = review.select_one('.ratingDate')['title'].strip()
                titre_rev_cl = review.select_one('.noQuotes').text.strip()
                opinion_cl = review.select_one('.partial_entry').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}", f"{date_rev_cl}" , f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]
                w.writerow(row)
```

For my settings, in order for this to work properly, I have to set delimiter as "," not ";"

Sample of results:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!...... It works perfectly for the ten first reviews (page 10), however It doesn't take into account the information from 11 to 40 pages. After review 10, it repeats the same 10 reviews to arrive to line 40.

Comment: I got unique values so not sure why that it happening for you.

Comment: yes, sorry!, I forgot type "offset" in the link page. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Excuse me, I have a question. At the end of some reviews, there is a word "plus" and it means that the review has other sentences or words after "plus". If I click over there I can see the complete review. Can you suggest me any article talking about that or one code to try to take the complete review?... I will appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Worth opening a new question. What I suspect is happening is that a new xhr request is issued when you click the plus and that request provides the full test. Have a go at monitoring the network tab and see if you see a new request made. Inspect the url of the new request and see if it contains an identifier that links it back to the comment you clicked on. Usually there is a parameter passed that identifies which plus sign you clicked.

Comment: I havnen't found the good way to get full text yet. When I inspect the url I have after <span class="taLnk ulBlueLinks" onclick="widgetEvCall('handlers.clickExpand',event,this);">Plus</span>......... I wrote a new question but people gave a solution that doesn't work for me. Can you helple me? ... what do i have to do to eliminate plus and get full text in the scraping?

Comment: Hi, the answer given by that person, from a quick read, looks like pretty much what I described in the comment above. If between you two you don't find where it is not working then let me know later today and I will write something.

Comment: We found where it wasn't working but now I'm trying to find the key to get information that I want. Normally,  I would have to get the information about 40 reviewers of a restaurant but when I look at the file it shows me 301 reviewers. The 40 reviewers are repeated at least five times. can you tell me what am I missing please? This is the final code : https://imgur.com/a/XGFiocL .

Comment: I will have a look

Comment: yes it is working but the question is that in the file I should have 30 reviews. I don't know why I have 301 reviews If I selected from 10 to 40 reviews, just 3 pages? the 30 reviews are repeated at least five times in the file. , I reallly don't understand..... This is some photos of  the file https://imgur.com/a/eyxcEV2 , https://imgur.com/a/sgg5xfk . Do you know what is happening?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it is working then. Presumably the error has to be from the code. Have you inspected the result coming back and ensured it is isn't combining results its returns?

Comment: yes, reviews variables and review values are repeated. I think maybe is that.

Comment: I have a question, can you check your code that you created here for answer to me please? is it working well?... No, the code has a Name error: name inf_rest_name is no defined .... line:row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}", f"{date_rev_cl}", f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]).

Comment: Excuse me. I'm sorry for asking a lot of questions but I need your help if you have time. I haven't found the way to get properly scraped information. I contintue having 301 reviews instead 31. I   tried to follow the answer to the questions "Data to .csv is repeating three times. I need three different scrapes exported to a csv file"   and "python repeating CSV"  but  for the first I understood nothing and the second doesn't work in my code. Can you help to get properly my code please? of course if you can.

Comment: Hi, open a question and describe the problem and be sure to include enough code to reproduce the problem. Add what you have tried. Drop a link to the new question here.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your disposition. I had just got the error, it was just a number in the loop for offset in range.